# Want to set an environment variable with TIME /t

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, time

I want to set a Windows environment variable from the results of TIME /t.

In Windows, the %time% variable yields one format (13:17:52.79), whereas TIME /t has another (01:17 PM).

I've tried sending it to a text file and trying to append "SET xxx=" but there is always a line feed that I cannot seem to eliminate.

For example, I can "ECHO Set xxx= >> TTT.txt" and "TIME /t >> TTT.txt" but the results are on two separate lines.  The same is true when I make two files and try to COPY /b.  I have also experimented with similar methods using WMIC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In cmd.exe, `for /f` can be used to read command output:

```
for /f %%a in ('time /t') do set xxx=%%a
```

See `for /?` for more details.

Comment: Thanks!  Almost there!  It misses the AM/PM.  I assume that's because there is a space in the output between the numbers and the AM/PM.  I read the /? for the "FOR" command and tried a few variations but no luck yet.

Comment: Ah, use `"tokens=*"` to catch multiple words.

Comment: That does it!  Thank you so much!  I've been fighting this for so long!